# Projections of the 3-dimensional phase-space of a non-autonomous ODE system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, graphics3d, nonlinear

Given classical system of ODE:

$\begin{cases} \dot{x}=g \\ \dot{g}=t \cdot (-g+\frac{df}{dx}) \\ \dot{h}=-h+\frac{d^2f}{d^2x} \end{cases}$

where $f = e^{-x^2}$

I am constructing a three-dimensional phase space as follows:

```
    f = Exp[-x^2]; dfdx = D[f, {x, 1}]; dfdx2 = D[f, {x, 2}];

    Manipulate[
 VectorPlot3D[{g, t (-g + dfdx), -h + dfdx2}, {x, -2, 2}, {g, -2, 
   2}, {h, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 1, 15}]
```

My mathematica version is 12.0, so the `StreamPlot3D` command is not supported for me, but I hope my results are correct.

**Questions:**

1. How to visualize the steady state point on this graph?
2. How to get projections of $x-g$,$x-h$ and $g-h$ planes?
3. Is it possible in an older version to build an analogue of the command `StreamPlot3D`.

Best regards to all specialists.

Comment: Isn't the system autonomous? (Does the dot indicate time-derivative? There's no time variable apparent in the equations.) — Won't the projections look like a pile of spaghetti? The basic idea would be to compute a bunch of trajectories and drop one of the coordinates when you `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: @Michael E2 Sorry. Mistake. I have corrected $k$ to $t$.

Comment: If we are talking about a three-dimensional system, as in my case, is it not necessary to use the ParametriсPlot3D command? But what command then build projections on the plane?

Comment: The x-g projection, for instance, of a single trajectory could be done `ParametricPlot[{x[t],g[t]} /. sol, {t, 1, 15}]`, no? (I'm talking about Q2.)

Comment: Oh, yes! Then I realized what you mean. By analogy, other trajectories can be visualized. But, we are talking about the projection of the phase space, not a three-dimensional trajectory! Do you understand me? That is, what I got using the VectorPlot3D command needs to be projected onto a plane.

Comment: "Phase space" of this *nonautonomous* system only makes sense to me as having the underlying coordinates `{t, x, g, h}`, with the corresponding vector field `{1, dx/dt, dg/dt, dh/dt}`.  Projection onto a coordinate plane involves plotting the corresponding coordinates.  Does that correspond to your idea?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alexei-Khalin/publication/226571130/figure/fig6/AS:668745429155842@1536452743190/Projections-of-3D-figures-onto-a-2D-plane-1-sphere-2-cone-3-pyramid.png

Comment: Generally. I will say even more. Imagine that in place of geometric shapes there are three-dimensional vector fields. And see what projections I want to get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125046/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-dtn).